# How to do pagination for a DTO that does not a match the structure of any entity in the project?

Tags: sorting, join, pagination, dto

I have created a DTO by using a named native query. I can display the list but I unable to sort or unable to do pagination on this DTO.

I have tried using repository findAll method for pagination and sorting. But, JPA repository can sort or do pagination if DTO is having same structure as an entity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Page<yourDTO>> yourMethod(@PathVariable @NotNull String param 1, Pageable pageable) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(yourService.yourMethod(param1, param2));
}
```

This is what your controller should return in order to get a pageable response. You can then sort based on the param you desire.